# Was Bitcoin 0.3.7 actually hard-forking?

Tags: script, blockchain-fork, consensus, history, op-return

Reading through the wiki [(bitcoin.it consensus versions)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Consensus_versions) I noticed that release 0.3.7 ("`scriptSig` + `scriptPubKey` evaluations separated") is listed as a hard-forking change. In BitMEX's [account of consensus forks](https://blog.bitmex.com/bitcoins-consensus-forks/), the same version is described as "potentially a non-deterministic hardfork". I would like to understand the rationale for this description.

In previous versions to 0.3.7, the `scriptSig` was concatenated to the `scriptPubKey`, and also allowed executable opcodes (such as `OP_RETURN`, at the time when it finished the script's execution without failing, allowing for the `OP_1 OP_RETURN` bug). The commit with the changes can be found [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/73aa262647ff9948eaf95e83236ec323347e95d0).

I guess disabling `OP_RETURN` can be considered a soft-fork, because previously valid transactions are now invalid. But I cannot come up with any example of a transaction, previously invalid, that would become valid after separating the evaluation of the `scriptSig` and `scriptPubKey`. The best I have come up with (with the old meaning of `OP_RETURN` in mind) is:

```
scriptSig: OP_2 (push the next 2 bytes to the stack)
scriptPubKey: OP_1 OP_RETURN OP_FALSE
```

Evaluated together, `OP_1 OP_RETURN` would be pushed to the stack as data instead of evaluated, therefore failing the script after `OP_FALSE`. However, when evaluated separately, the `scriptPubKey` would pass as valid (... but not the `scriptSig`, for providing no data to push?).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. An invalid pair of arguments to `CHECKSIG` can become valid after the fork. This is because the `scriptSig` is evaluated too.

```
scriptPubKey: OP_TRUE
scriptSig: <sig> <pubkey> OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY
```

Before the fork, `sig` [would be checked](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/73aa262647ff9948eaf95e83236ec323347e95d0#diff-27496895958ca30c47bbb873299a2ad7a7ea1003a9faa96b317250e3b7aa1fefL1153) with a `scriptCode` containing the concatenation of the `scriptSig`, a `CODESEPARATOR`, and the `scriptPubKey`.
After the fork, `sig` [would be checked](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/73aa262647ff9948eaf95e83236ec323347e95d0#diff-27496895958ca30c47bbb873299a2ad7a7ea1003a9faa96b317250e3b7aa1fefR1117-R1120) with a `scriptCode` containing only the `scriptSig` itself.

Therefore the hashes differ and a signature could be valid after the fork whereas it was invalid before.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but perhaps scripts using the alt stack (which IIRC is cleared with the split execution)?